# Solr Error Timeout occured while waiting response from server

Tags: solr4

I am new to Solr,I am using solr 4.3.0, I had indexed near about 100gb of data into the solr.When I search into the solr, sometime it gives me timeout error.

Error Message

```
got org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Timeout occured while waiting response from server at: http://localhost:8983/solr/triplestore
[error]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:409)
[error]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:180)
[error]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:90)
[error]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
```

Help appreciated :)

Comment: Hi, could you solve the problem? Did the indexing complete?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by increasing the timeout values in solr.xml

```
<solr>

  <int name="maxBooleanClauses">${solr.max.booleanClauses:1024}</int>
  
  <solrcloud>

    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>

    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>

    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateSoTimeout">${distribUpdateSoTimeout:1200000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateConnTimeout">${distribUpdateConnTimeout:120000}</int>
    <str name="zkCredentialsProvider">${zkCredentialsProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkCredentialsProvider}</str>
    <str name="zkACLProvider">${zkACLProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkACLProvider}</str>

  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <!-- changed timeout values from 60000ms (10 mins) to 1200000ms (20 mins) -->
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:1200000}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:1200000}</int>
    <str name="shardsWhitelist">${solr.shardsWhitelist:}</str>
  </shardHandlerFactory>

</solr>
```